# Ajax enabled WCF: no data received

Tags: jquery, wcf

I am new with WCF so please bear with me.

I have a simple WCF service accepting a simple JSON data like this {name: "Joe Boxer"}. The should just echo back the name passed.

---

```
Imports System.ServiceModel
Imports System.ServiceModel.Activation
Imports System.ServiceModel.Web
Imports System.Runtime.Serialization

<ServiceContract(Namespace:="")>
<AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode:=AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)>
Public Class Service

    <Serializable()> _
    <DataContract(Name:="Person")> _
    Public Class Person
        <DataMember(IsRequired:=True, Name:="Name")> _
        Public Name As String
    End Class

    <OperationContract()>
    <WebInvoke(requestformat:=WebMessageFormat.Json)>
    Public Function GetName(ByVal p As Person) As String
        Return "Your name is " & p.Name
    End Function

End Class
```

---

So, I used JQuery AJAX and JSON2 to do POST to the WCF. I can see with firebug the JSON data passed. However, the GetName() method always never can see the data passed - making the code fail because p is null.

It seems like this service cannot see any data passed.

What am I missing? Thank you in advance for your help.

Thanks Pradeep for your response.

I am actually sending a complex type. Sorry, if did not make it clear. Here's how I am sending it (simplified).

```
$.ajax( { 
url: "http://localhost/wcftest/service.svc/GetName",
data: JSON.stringify({name:"Joe Boxer"}),
type: "POST",
processData: false,
contentType: "application/json; charset=UTF-8",
timeout: 10000,
dataType: "json", 
success: function(res) { alert(res); },
error:  function() { alert("error"); return;} 
});
```

I can see in firebug {"name":"Joe Boxer"} is being sent. But the function still doesn't see it. I am probably overlooking something really small but I don't know what. I've been playing with this all day.

Answer (score 0):

Data that you are sending from client is not right. You are just posting a string. In WCF you are not expecting string but you are expecting a complex type (Person) Post the structure of `Person` and then your WCF should do the work.

[using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex](http://encosia.com/2009/04/07/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/) should help you achieve what you want to do.
HTH

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is JSON parsing is case sensitive and you're passing "name" from the client while your `DataMemberAttribute` has "Name". Try changing one side or the other so that they match in case.